# Part screen Android application, always on top

Tags: android

Hello fellow programers!

I'm trying to figur out if it is possible to develop an application that:

1. Does not cover the whole screen, and hence, can interact with the application or OS behind.
2. Always is on top of the other application.

I'm thinking something along the windows-forms on a PC, that can be resized and moved around.
Also, I'm using API 15, but could if necessary change to API 17.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sony use something called small apps https://play.google.com/store/search?q=small+apps&c=apps, try researching this? http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/1240/1240459/small-app-tutorial-184485-0-s-307x512.jpg

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be it!